# Auto create a record on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I´m a begginer Rails developer and i´m into a trouble.

I have done an aplication for monitoring a sensor, and now i want to send the valus from an arduino board.

I wanto to create atomatically a record accesing to a url like "localhost/values/343#123" only form the local machine.

What´s the way? It´s is possible?

Thank You!!!

Comment: Does the Arduino send the data via http?

Comment: Yes Mark, typically with a GET.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a POST request via HTTP.

The Restful, Railsy way to to it would be to do a POST to the url ending in the pluralized name of the class of the record you want to create. So, "/values." As long as your values match columns in the Values table, you can use the Scaffold controllers, and you will create a new record with the values you pass.